# Advance Approval API call for bulk records

Tags: cpq, approval-process, advanced, cpq-api

Has anyone worked on or has idea about the calling Advance Approval APIs for bulk records?
The goal is to Submit multiple records for Approval, with current SBAA.ApprovalAPI's we can call it only for one record at a time and we will hit governor limits if try to iterate it.

To be more specific, I am trying to Submit all the QuoteLines at once using APEX from Quote.

The approach that I used is to iterate all the QuoteLine and call SBAA.ApprovalAPI but it will result into SOQL 101 error at some point. Tried using Batch Apex with size 1 and ended up with another issue of "UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record"

I am looking for a robust solution for this where there are multiple Quote Lines needed for approval to be able to submit all at once.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced approval API will accept the approval record's ID and approve/reject as an argument. What I can suggest is :

1. Write a SOQL to grab the approval records for the quote, store them in an array.
2. Loop through that array and in each iteration call the adv approval API and approve the approval record.
3. Once all the approval records related to quote are approved, final approval status of the quote will also change.

As I see in the documentation it does not give a provision to bulk approve in one go.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already tried this approach using batch, most of the records are going through Approval but strangely a few records failed to submit with error “unable to obtain exclusive access to this record: [QuoteID]”.

Comment: This error comes when two process try to lock the same resource for processing, in this case (the parent quote might be locked). So first approach to overcome this is use dead wait based on your experience (not an ideal way). 2: Poll for the approval records to completely get approved or rejected before iterating over the next approval records. I believe the advanced approval API might not have fully finished processing the earlier approval record IDs before proceeding to following ones leading to error.